# ClaudiaJS - How to add S3 write permission to Lambda Function

Tags: claudiajs

My ClaudiaJS API is working fine but I cannot store images files on an S3 bucket.

The problem is because the Lambda Function has no permission to Write on S3.

Question: How can I tell ClaudiaJS to include an S3 Write permission into the Lambda Function Permissions?

Comment: Can you confirm you have IAM permissions that include S3 write policies..?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.